# ADODB command value of wrong type error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I've been trying to crack this issue for a while and I've almost got it I think. I am using the following code to update a SQL table. This sub executes on a button click. When clicked I get "Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation" error.

It highlights the `Pm.Value = myarray` line. In the locals window I can see that `myarray` is pulling in the correct value, which is a name selected from a listbox on a userform.

```vb
Sub testingcommand()
database_connect
Dim AttendRecord As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
Dim myarray As Variant
Dim Pm As ADODB.Parameter
myarray = GetSelectedItems(attendance.Agentname)
If Appconn.State = 0 Then
Call database_connect
End If
Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
With Cm
    .ActiveConnection = Appconn
    .CommandText = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [Seated] = '1' WHERE [Agentname]=?;"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    Set Pm = .CreateParameter("AgentName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, "myarray")
    Pm.value = myarray
    .Parameters.Append Pm
    Set AttendRecord = .Execute
End With
Set AttendRecord = Nothing
PhoneHiring_Disconnect
End Sub
```

I've edited this with the function that is returning the array.

```vb
 Public Function GetSelectedItems(lBox As MSForms.ListBox) As Variant


 Dim tmpArray() As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim selCount As Integer

    selCount = -1
    For i = 0 To lBox.ListCount - 1
        If lBox.Selected(i) = True Then
            selCount = selCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray(selCount)
            tmpArray(selCount) = lBox.list(i)

        End If
    Next
    If selCount = -1 Then
        GetSelectedItems = Array()
    Else
        GetSelectedItems = tmpArray
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot assign an array to a parameter expecting a single value.  If you have a list of items then you need to do it in a loop or use a "...where in(...)" clause

Comment: Is function `GetSelectedItems` returns a string?

Comment: ^ what @Tim said. also it looks like you're using some global-scope connection... that's sloppy: a database connection should be as tightly scoped as possible, even more so than any other type of variable - imagine you open a file *somewhere* and keep the handle global and *something, somewhere, at some point*, is going to close it: it's a recipe for problems. If you don't know exactly what the next command is and when it will be issued, it's time to close that connection.

Comment: @nagarajannd if that were the case, OP wouldn't be having this error. `myarray As Variant`, and the pluralization of `GetSelectedItems`, suggest rather strongly that the function is returning an array of strings.

Comment: I've added the Getselecteditems function code so you guys can see it. It is returning a string. It should be able to return multiple strings if multiple items are selected but in this case it is only selecting one.

Comment: Thanks for including the code. It is *not* returning a string. `Array()` is an empty **array**, and `tmpArray` is declared as a variant **array** as well. Neither are strings. An array that contains only one string *is still an array*.

Comment: Any idea how to get it to work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```vb
Sub testingcommand()

    Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
    Dim myarray As Variant
    Dim Pm As ADODB.Parameter, v

    myarray = GetSelectedItems(attendance.Agentname)
    If Appconn.State = 0 Then
        Call database_connect
    End If

    Set Cm = New ADODB.Command
    With Cm
        .ActiveConnection = Appconn
        .CommandText = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [Seated] = '1' WHERE [Agentname]=?"
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        Set Pm = .CreateParameter("AgentName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 200, "myarray")
        .Parameters.Append Pm

        'loop over your array
        for each v in myarray
            Pm.value = v
            .Execute
        Next v

    End With
    Set AttendRecord = Nothing
    PhoneHiring_Disconnect

End Sub
```

Comment: That will only work for single-selections because of the `=` in the `WHERE` clause ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - hence the loop?

Comment: Oh, I totally missed you were executing the command multiple times over - yeah that'll work... although the ideal solution would be both parameterized *and* set-based.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you! You've solved MULTIPLE issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead appending parameters build the query string and execute them

```vb
With Cm
    .ActiveConnection = Appconn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    For Each x In myarray
        x = "'" & x & "'"
    Next
    .CommandText = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [Seated] = '1' WHERE [Agentname] In ('" & VBA.Join(myarray, "','") & "')"
    Set AttendRecord = .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Or just `"UPDATE [Attendance] SET [Seated] = '1' WHERE [Agentname] In ('" & VBA.Join(myarray, "','") & "')"`

Comment: Your loop doesn't affect the content of myArray - `x` is a *copy* of each element, not a reference to it.

Comment: Sorry! Totally missed that. :( @Mathieu Guindon Thanks for the edit.